# c++ string vector change element

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

void test(vector<string> tab) {
    tab[1]=tab[2];
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> tab;
    tab.push_back("1");
    tab.push_back("2");
    tab.push_back("3");
    tab.push_back("4");
    tab.push_back("5");
    tab.push_back("6");
    test(tab);
    for (int i = 0; i < tab.size(); i++) {
        cout << tab[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

Why function test doesn't work? Don't change element in vector tab...
I don't know what I am do wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The parameter `tab` is passed by value, it'll be copied from the argument, any modification in the function has nothing to do with the original argument.

You can change it to pass-by-reference.

```
void test(vector<string>& tab) {
//                      ^
    tab[1]=tab[2];
}
```